# Pointer to array of double or array of pointers?

Tags: c, variables, definition

I'm maintaining a part of code written by my friend, here's a definition of a variable called `d`:

```
double (*d)[3];
```

I tried to initialize the variable using the code below but in each part there is an error (runtime or compilation). I have gotten confused whether variable `d` is a pointer to array of double or array of pointers to double.

```
double k;
(*d)[0] = k; // runtime error using gcc compiler
d[0] = &k;   // Compilation error, assignment to expression with array type
*d = &k;     // Compilation error, assignment to expression with array type
```

Comment: It would help if you tagged the programming language.   Yes, there are people who will recognise the language just from the code.   But not everyone will do that.

Comment: Remember the spiral rule: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `d` variable is a pointer to a 3 length `double` array. So you can assign a pointer of a `double[3]` array to it. For example:

```
double (*d)[3];
double a[3] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
d = &a;
```

But to make it more practical, you can also use dynamic memory allocation. For example:

```
double (*d)[3];
d = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
d[0][0] = 1.0;
d[0][1] = 2.0;
d[0][2] = 3.0;
printf("%f %f %f\n", d[0][0], d[0][1], d[0][2]);
```

This way, `d` will point to a single, 3-length `double` array. The program will give the following output:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
```

By the way, you can replace e.g. `d[0][0]` with `(*d)[0]`, they mean exactly the same.

Comment: Great answer. Something I want to add is casting `malloc` output ( pointer to double ) is not perform implicitly in my `DEV` compiler. And I had to use `d = (double (*)[3]) malloc (3 * sizeof(double));` instead.

Comment: Then change your compiler. In C, you don't cast malloc, its not C++!